# path element showing in dom but not connected in svg

Tags: d3.js, svg, path, selector

path element shows as individual points in the dom instead of one string of elements in SVG.  The code looks like this

```
//------ BEGIN NEW CODE HERE ------
let univMenu = d3.select("#univDropdown");

univMenu
.append("select")
.selectAll("option")
.data(nest)
.enter()
.append("option")
.attr("value", function(d){return d.key;})
.text(function(d){return d.key;})



// Function to create the initial graph
let initialGraph = function(univ){


let selectUniv = nest.filter(function(d){return d.key == univ;})
let selectUnivGroups = svg.selectAll(".univGroups")
.data(selectUniv, function(d){return d ? d.key : this.key;})
.enter()
.append("g")
.attr("class", "univGroups")

let initialPath = selectUnivGroups.selectAll(".line")
.data(function(d) { return d.values; })
.enter()
.append("path")

initialPath
.attr("d", function(d){return valueLine(d.values)})
.attr("class", "line")}
// Create initial graph
initialGraph("USHE Average")


// Update the data
let updateGraph = function(univ){

// Filter the data to include only fruit of interest
let selectUniv = nest.filter(function(d){return d.key == univ;})

// Select all of the grouped elements and update the data
let selectUnivGroups = svg.selectAll(".univGroups")
.data(selectUniv)

// Select all the lines and transition to new positions
selectUnivGroups.selectAll("path.line")
.data(function(d){return (d.values);})
.transition()
.duration(1000)

.attr("d", function(d){return valueLine(d.values)})}


// Run update function when dropdown selection changes
univMenu.on('change', function(){
    let selectedUniv = d3.select(this)
        .select("select")
        .property("value")


    updateGraph(selectedUniv)


});
```

The idea is I would have a selector to toggle between different universities to show their cost through the 'univMenu'.
Any help to get the path to show individually would be very greatly appreciated.  I have the style in the CSS.

EDIT: the valueLine variable is defined as:

```
var valueLine = d3.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.Year); })
.y(function(d) { return y(+d.Currentdollars); });
```

A sample of the CSV is

```
University,USHE average,Constant dollars,Currentdollars,Year,% change from 
previous year
University of Utah,NA,"$49,711 ",56990.00,2008,NA
```

Comment: Please update your post with the source for the `valueLine(...)` function, and a sample of the data structure you are using...

Comment: Thanks for looking it over SteveR.  I updated my post to show the valueLine and a sample of the data.

Comment: Set `.attr("d", valueLine)`, like in the example at https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion ccprog.  d is currently set as a function of the valueLine passed through the nested variable.  I did try running it with just the valueLine with no success.  I will continue trying different methods.  Thanks again for the suggestion!